# Undefined request Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, api, express, body-parser

Here I want to post data on server but I'm not able to do so. I receive the error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I am using `body-parser`.undefined object.am i import references right way in StudentRoute.js file , i check post method in App.js where work right , but in studentRoute.js file post method not working .

StudentRoute.js file

```
import express from 'express'; 
var app = express();
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import students from '../data/students.json';

const router=express.Router();


let studentsArray=students;


router.get('/:id',(req,res)=>{      //like here replace '/:id'
    const studnet=_.find(studentsArray,studnet=>studnet.id==req.params.id);
    if(studnet){
        res.json(studnet);
    }
    else
    {
         res.send(`User with id:${req.params.id} not found`);
    }

});

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json(studentsArray)
    res.end();
}); 
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("post request");
    console.log(req.body);
    students.studentsArray.push(req.body);
    res.status(200).send("OK");
});   
router.put('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("put request") 
    res.end();
});
router.delete('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("Delete request")
    res.end();
    });

router.param('id',(req,res,next,id)=>{
        if(isNaN(id)){
            next(`${id} Not a number`);
        }
        next();
    });    

 module.exports=router;
```

Other file APP.js

```
import express from 'express';
import students from './data/students.json';
import StudentRoute from './routes/StudentRoute';
import _ from 'lodash';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import https from 'https';
const port=3000;

const buildurl=(version,path)=>`/api/${version}/${path}`; 
const STUDENT_BASE_URL=buildurl('v1','students');

const server=express();

server.use(morgan('tiny'));
server.use(STUDENT_BASE_URL,StudentRoute);

server.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`server started on port ${port}`);

});
```

Comment: i solve my self : need to use  use(express.bodyParser()) before  use(app.router). In fact, app.use(app.router) should be the last thing you call

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you find a solution to your question on your own you should answer your own question. This way you can accept your own answer and the question will appear as answered to anyone browsing. Type your solution into the answer box, post your answer and click on the checkmark next to your answer to accept it.